# How to cast an object returned from a function in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

In the virtual method `create()` in the derived class `Derived`, I return a struct of type `HelpDerived`. However, since I had to set the return type of the method to `HelpBase`, I found that I need to cast the returned object back to the type `HelpDerived`.

The following is an example of my case.

```
#include <iostream>


struct HelpBase {
    int a = 0;
    virtual void output() {}
};

struct HelpDerived : HelpBase {
    int b = 0;
    void output() override {}
};


class Base {
public:
    virtual HelpBase create() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    HelpBase create() override;
};

HelpBase Derived::create() {
    HelpDerived d;
    d.a = 1;
    d.b = 2;
    return d;
}


int main() {
    Derived d;
    auto based = d.create();
    HelpDerived derived = dynamic_cast<HelpDerived &>(based);

    std::cout << derived.a << std::endl;
}
```

When I run the code abve, I get the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Abort trap: 6
```

What have I misunderstood about objects and casting in C++? Why does this method not work?

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: You have an object of type `HelpBase` , not `HelpDerived`- I guess you are confused by the object slicing you perform inside the `create` function?

Comment: Polymorphism is supposed to work with pointers or references, otherwise you're subject to object slicing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: In the `Derived::create` function when you return `d` you [*slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) the object, leaving you with nothing but the `HelpBase` object being returned. The variable `based` is a `HelpBase` object, there's no way to get back the original `HelpDerived` objects once used in the `create` function.

Comment: Thanks, now I at least understand what causes my problem. But Im still not sure how to fix it. Should I make the `create` method return a pointer to a `HelpBase` object instead?

Comment: Returning a pointer to HelpBase is one possibility. You can even override it with a function that returns a pointer to HelpDerived (google covariant return types).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better return a pointer to avoid object slicing in your `create` function.

```
#include <iostream>


struct HelpBase {
    int a = 0;
    virtual void output() {}
};

struct HelpDerived : HelpBase {
    int b = 0;
    void output() override {}
};


class Base {
public:
    virtual HelpBase* create() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    HelpBase* create() override;
};

HelpBase* Derived::create() {
    HelpDerived* d = new HelpDerived;
    d->a = 1;
    d->b = 2;
    return d;
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    auto based = d.create();
    HelpDerived* derived = dynamic_cast<HelpDerived *>(based);

    std::cout << derived->a << " " << derived->b << std::endl;
    delete derived;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced dynamic cast by static cast and it worked for me almost fine.

```
#include <iostream>


struct HelpBase {
    int a = 0;
    virtual void output() {}
};

struct HelpDerived : HelpBase {
    int b = 0;
    void output() override {}
};


class Base {
public:
    virtual HelpBase create() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    HelpBase create() override;
};

HelpBase Derived::create() {
    HelpDerived d;
    d.a = 3;
    d.b = 2;
    return d;
}


int main() {
    Derived d;
    auto based = d.create();
    HelpDerived derived = static_cast<HelpDerived &>(based);

    std::cout << derived.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << derived.b << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

**3**

***32726***

Note that **a** value is correct, while **b** is junk. This is because for **derived** constructor has not been called.
In general, casting from base class to derived is not recommended, as derived may have more data members, than base class.
Recommended reading: https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php

Comment: The derived constructor is absolutely called, the issue is object slicing.  Your answer doesn't actually solve the problem.